# Error C1083 (file not found) with CMAKE target_include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a c++ project split into a few different libraries/executables in the source tree. There is a top level CMake file that includes some subdirectories. One leaf library B links against another leaf library A. However, even though A has added target_include_directories publicly, in B, I get the error C1083 - cannot open include file.

OS: Win10

Using kit GCC 7.3.0:

- CMake Command `"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DMOCK_SIMCONNECT:BOOL=TRUE "-DP3D_SDK_ROOT:STRING=C:/Program Files/Lockheed Martin/Prepar3D v4 SDK 4.5.14.34698" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\g++.exe -Hd:/repos/cmake_sample_project -Bd:/repos/cmake_sample_project/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"`
- Error Message:

```
[build] D:\repos\cmake_sample_project\src\B\libB.h:5:10: fatal error: libA.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include "libA.h"
[build]           ^~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
```

Using kit Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 Release - amd64:

- CMake command: `"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DMOCK_SIMCONNECT:BOOL=TRUE "-DP3D_SDK_ROOT:STRING=C:/Program Files/Lockheed Martin/Prepar3D v4 SDK 4.5.14.34698" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -Hd:/repos/cmake_sample_project -Bd:/repos/cmake_sample_project/build -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -T host=x64 -A x64`
- Error Message:

```
d:\repos\cmake_sample_project\src\b\libB.h(5): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "libA.h": No such file or directory [D:\repos\cmake_sample_project\build\src\B\libB-obj.vcxproj]
```

```
sample_cmake_project
|   CMakeLists.txt
|   
+---src
|   |   CMakeLists.txt
|   |   
|   +---A
|   |   |   CMakeLists.txt
|   |   |   libA.cpp
|   |   |   
|   |   \---public
|   |           libA.h
|   |           
|   \---B
|           CMakeLists.txt
|           libB.cpp
|           libB.h
|           
\---tests
        CMakeLists.txt
```

sample_cmake_project/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(sample_project LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

sample_cmake_project/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(A)
add_subdirectory(B)
```

sample_cmake_project/src/A/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(libA-obj OBJECT "")

target_sources(libA-obj 
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libA.cpp
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public/libA.h # <-- header is added as public source.
)

add_library(libA STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libA-obj>)

target_include_directories(libA PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public) # <-- public dir is added to the target's PUBLIC include directories.

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public)
```

sample_cmake_project/src/B/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(libB-obj OBJECT "")

target_sources(libB-obj 
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libB.cpp
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libB.h
)

add_library(libB STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libA-obj>)

target_link_libraries(libB PRIVATE libA)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

sample_cmake_project/src/A/public/libA.h:

```
#ifndef __LIBA_H
#define __LIBA_H

#include <iostream>

class A 
{
    public:
    A() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; };
    ~A() { std::cout << "bye bye" << std::endl; };

    void saySomething();
};

#endif
```

sample_cmake_project/src/A/libA.cpp:

```
#include "libA.h"

void A::saySomething()
{
    std::cout << "something..." << std::endl;
}
```

sample_cmake_project/src/B/libB.h:

```
#ifndef __LIB_B
#define __LIB_B

#include <iostream>
#include "libA.h"

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();

    void saySomething();

private:
    A _a;
};

#endif
```

sample_cmake_project/src/B/libB.cpp:

```
#include "libB.h"

B::B() :
    _a(A())
{
    std::cout << "Hello from lib B" << std::endl;
    _a.saySomething();
}
```

I feel I might be missing something fundamental, but I thought that by adding sample_cmake_project/A/public to the libA target's include directories, the libA.h header should be available for the libraries that link against libA, e.g. libB?

any thouhts? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce. All targets are built successfully. You real code seems to be different.

Comment: Please, provide the **exact error message**.

Comment: I updated the answer and by taking another look at the error messages, I realized that the file was missing from libB-obj, the objects library used to build the static library. libB-obj wasn't being linked to libA, then it's obvious it wouldn't find the include directories. It was very easy to see after your comment and a good night's sleep.

Answer (score 0):

It was trivial and kinda obvious, but I overlooked it. The error messages refer to libB-obj, the objects library used to make the static library libB. libB-obj wasn't linked to libA, hence the public include directories from libA weren't available for libB-obj.

```
add_library(libB-obj OBJECT "")

target_sources(libB-obj 
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libB.cpp
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libB.h
)

add_library(libB STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libA-obj>)

target_link_libraries(libB-obj PRIVATE libA) # --> link libB-obj instead of static library libB!

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```